# Can adding o-rings in mechanical keyboards alleviate RSI?

Tags: computers, repetitive-strain-injury

I have read many claims from individuals that adding o-rings in mechanical keyboards alleviate RSI. The reasoning is that it allows shock absorption, which minimizes finger fatigue (e.g., according to [this product's description](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00AZQ2OF8)) and strain on the wrists and forearms.

Is there any scientific study confirming or infirming the claim?

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.